# A/B testing of parameter similar to Conversion rate , What distribution to assume?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

I have a set-up where users can watch from 0 to N amount of videos  , lets say : 
Videos per users[VPU]  = sum(videos) /sum(users). i have above 200K users  for each A/B split . I want to check if VPU in A is different from VPU in B.

But , what is the right way to check the correct distribution (and the right test for it? ) My parameter is similar to conversion rate which is Binomial , but the user can have multiple states rather then "convert/not convert" .

Also any references for further reading and learning will be really good . thank you!

---UPDATE--- Here is the distribution of, each sample is the amount of videos user watched.

[image: Distribution]

Comment: you could look at survival/churn analysis

Comment: Rates and proportions are not automatically binomial.

Comment: @seanv507  ,Thanks (was interesting to read ) but its not very similar to our model. my set-up is more like a video player who play videos while user is on the website , the behavior of the user is not the only thing that will effect the occurrence of videos .. we can think of it as click through rate but user can click more then once ..

Comment: sorry, misread your question.  I think you had better look at count data regression(https://books.google.de/books?id=qVEwBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false).  Would you mind plotting a histogram of user views (ie how many users viewed 0 videos, 1,...10 videos,...(eg to give an impression whether videos viewed is normally distributed)

Comment: I've added the histogram

Comment: try taking some logs and see how the data looks like, another direction is to search for preferential attachment distributions

Comment: We have decided to do a two-step approach . Since most of the samples are 0 then the "non zero" is a more rare sample , we can look at it as 1. Users watched  video or not ? (0 / 0< )  . 2.  Changes in the >0 distribution: given the user did watched a video -  do we have differences between amount of videos watched per user in A vs B. which seems like poisson distribution . What do you think?